# Sitecore 7.5 upgrade

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore7.5

I am upgrading Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore 7.5 .
Everything went good, but when I have to convert data for analytics I see many errors passing. First I did it without WFFM parameters, which worked perfectly.
Then a restored my original database and executed the same command with the WFFM parameters.
Now is see hundreds of erros passing in my conversion tool:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool
 at Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool.ConversionPipeline.<Process>b__2(VisitsRow    v)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
 at    Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool.ConversionPipeline.Process(VisitExtensionArgs args)
at     ...
```

Anyone who has an idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and raised a support issue with Sitecore. Their answer was that the documentation in the xDB Upgrade and Conversion Guide is wrong with regards to the data reader type.

The documentation says:

/wffmreadertype "Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool.Reader.SqlServerReader, Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool"

It should be:

/wffmreadertype Sitecore.Forms.ConversionTool.Reader.SqlServerReader

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sitecore told me exactly the same and it worked :)